# One sub-process blocks another sub-process when both communicates with a parent process through a pipe

Tags: c, fork, pipe

my Process Programming teacher made me write a program on C that creates four childs and makes them calculate the first, second, third and fourth quarters respectively, of a range of numbers, giving the parent all the prime numbers on them.

I coded correctly the first child quarter, but when I added the second child the program's behavior comes uncontrolable. My teacher and I have spent about 2 hours looking depth in the code and we've not found the problem.

The code is this as I have it right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void main(){

    unsigned long long a=500000,b,c; // not used yet -> d,e,i;
    pid_t pid1;
    unsigned long long fin = 0; //This is used in each child to write if it has finished the prime number calculation.
    unsigned long long fin1 = 0, fin2 = 0; //This is used on the parent to check if a child has finished.
    int primo = 0; //This is used to know if a number is a prime number.
int fd1[2]; //Pipe which communicates the parent with the first child.
    int fd2[2]; //Pipe which communicates the parent with the second child.
//  int fd3[2]; //Not used yet
//  int fd4[4]; //Not used yet
    pipe(fd1); //First child pipe
    pipe(fd2); //Second child pipe
//  pipe(fd3); //Not used yet
//  pipe(fd4); //Not used yet
    pid1 = fork(); //Creating first child
        switch (pid1){
            case -1: //Error
                printf("Error creating child.");
                exit(-1);
            case 0: //First child
                close(fd1[0]); //Input close
                for(b=100;b<(a/4);b++){         //
                    for(i=2;i<b/2;i++){     // These loops check each number from 100 to 125000
                        if(b%i==0){     // and if it is NOT a prime number, it breaks and tries
                            primo=0;    // to check the next number.
                            break;      //                  
                        }           //
                        primo=1;        //      
                    }
                    if(primo==1){               //If it IS a prime number, it's written on the pipe
                        write(fd1[1], &b, sizeof(b));   //and sent to the parent.
                    }
                }
                fin=1; //The child sets it has finished calculating and writes it in the pipe to tell his parent.
                write(fd1[1], &fin, sizeof(fin));
                close(fd1[1]); //Output closing
                break; //First child ends
            default: //Parent

                pid1 = fork(); //Creating second child
                    switch (pid1) {

                        case -1: //error
                            printf("Error");
                            exit(-1);
                        case 0: //Sencond child
                            close(fd2[0]);                      //This behavior is EXACTLY equals to the first child behavior
                            for(c=(a/4);c<(a/2);c++){               //
q                               for(i=2;i<c/2;i++){             //
                                    if(c%i==0){             //
                                        primo=0;            //
                                        break;              //
                                    }                   //
                                primo=1;                    //
                                }                       //
                                if(primo==1){                   //
                                    write(fd2[1], &c, sizeof(c));       //
                                }                       //
                            }                           //
                            fin=1;                          //
                            write(fd2[1], &fin, sizeof(fin));           //
                            close(fd2[1]);                      //
                            break;                              
                        default: //Parent           
                            //HERE WOULD COME THE CODE FOR THIRD AND FOURTH CHILDS.
                            break;



                    } //second child switch close

                //Parent reads answers from childs
                close(fd1[1]); //First child output closing
                close(fd2[1]); //Second child output closing
                for(;;){ //Infinite loop
                    if(fin1==0){ //If first child HAS NOT finished (As it sends a 1 if it does)
                        read(fd1[0], &b, sizeof(b)); //Read the prime number
                        if(b==1){ //If it is a 1, then the child has finished.
                            fin1=1;  //We set the first child has finished
                            close(fd1[0]); //First child input closing
                        }else{
                            printf("%llu es primo\n", b); //Otherwise it is a prime number, then it's printed to console.
                        }   
                    }   
                    if(fin2==0){                        //Same behavior as with first child
                        read(fd2[0], &c, sizeof(c));
                        if(c==1){
                            fin2=1;
                            close(fd2[0]);
                        }else{
                            printf("%llu es primo\n", c);
                        }   
                    }
                    if(fin1==1&&fin2==1){ //If both childs have finished, then we exit.
                        exit(0);
                    }                   
                }
                break;

        }
    exit(0);
}
```

It appears to be correct, but it doesn't work properly. When the second child finishes calculating its range of numbers (From 125000 to 249999) it blocks the first child and the first child stops.

Then the program enters in an infinite loop of reading and printing the pipe's content
And it looks like this:

```
[first child last calculated number] es primo
250000 es primo
[first child last calculated number] es primo
250000 es primo
[first child last calculated number] es primo
250000 es primo
[first child last calculated number] es primo
250000 es primo
```

And so. So we ask HOW 250000 could have been written to the pipe and read from the parent, and why the second child finishing blocks the first child.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at line 67 your code breaks out of the second switch statement (line 45). Execution resumes at line 77. So child process 2 is trying to close ( fd2[1] ) twice. Child process 2 is executing code targetted at parent process.

You could try replacing line 67 with

```
exit(0);
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked properly. Anyway, I wish to know where a 250000 appears, if you could tell me.

Comment: Suggest you write boolean function isPrime(

Comment: Suggest you write boolean function isPrime(long candidatePrime, long testDenominator).  Best use a list of prime numbers, not every number. The max testDenominator is sqrt( candidatePrime) - note sqrt is double, not long in ansi c.